# Using LibGDX within Android Fragment

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to use LibGDX with Android, but instead of modifying my Activity to extend

> AndroidApplication

I want my to render my graphics inside Android [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

The problem is that my class already extends Fragment, so I can't make it extend LibGDX AndroidApplication (Multiple Inheritance)

is there any workaround for this ?

Thanks

Comment: You would probably just complicate things by taking out pretty much one of the core features of libgdx. Where does the need come from to make it so complex?

Comment: I need to display a 3D model in the fragment, then display some info in another view in the activity

Comment: If I'm not mistaken libgdx supports 3D rendering. Not sure though.

Comment: Seems like it's still in progess: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html Sorry can't help you there =[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after searching I got this solution:

instead of using a fragment I used a generic View to render my graphics in it:

```
game=new MyGdxGame(); 
View gameView=initializeForView(game,cfg);
```

this is how I was able to display other views in my activity

Answer (score 3):

I just made a [pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/1286) with the fragment feature implemented.

Instead of extending `AndroidApplication` by an activity, you can extend `AndroidFragmentApplication` by a `Fragment` and return `initializeForView()` on the `onCreateView` callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe you want to share the url of your repo to help other users with this